# If a creator of a Shield Guardian gives the control amulet to the Shield Guardian, what would happen?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, summoning

There was an idea pitched at one of my play sessions earlier this week that has been gnawing at me. Suppose a wizard creates a shield guardian and gives the golem the telepathic command to put on the amulet and live a life of its own; what would happen?

Would the Shield Guardian become a sort of pseudo-warforged, following the original command? Would it just be stuck, standing there?

Comment: Can this be narrowed down to a single question and situation?  I think the shield guardian is sufficiently interesting and narrow to have an answer to "what would happen..."

Comment: FYI, I removed your second question to focus this on the shield guardian. YOu can absolutely ask the other question, separately.

Comment: And welcome to our stack! Please take the [tour] to learn more about us and you can visit the [help] for more information about how we operate.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Your title mentions giving the amulet *to the guardian* and then your body mentions commanding the guardian to *remove the amulet*. Could you clarify the situation you are describing?

Comment: Did anyone else think of Terry Pratchett's *Feet of Clay* when they saw this question?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## A shield guardian that owned its own amulet would guard itself.

It would simply protect itself as that is its only focus.

> A shield guardians solitary focus is to protect the amulet's wearer. The amulet's wearer can command the guardian to attack its enemies or to guard the wielder against attack.

Given it has intelligence and wisdom, that would primarily involve moving out of the way of foreseeable harm.  It may not always flee as it has the capacity to assess fighting or fleeing from harm.

### It would not resemble a warforged

Warforged have other varied interests, focuses, and lives to live.  In contrast, a shield guardian has no other focus than protecting the wearer (itself) from harm.

Comment: So if it had a high enough intelligence and awareness of the world and could think ahead, that'd likely give it a 'semblance' of humanity, though only through decisions to protect itself.

Comment: @CannedMawloc I support GcL's answer as RAW, given the narrow focus of what the amulet wearer can command the guardian to do. But I do like your idea! As a DM, I would be inclined to consider this as an interesting plot point - given time and circumstance, could such a shield guardian gain sentience?

Comment: What about the case of commanding it to remove the amulet?

Comment: @NautArch usually the verbal component to _flaunt command_ is "neeneer neener. you can't make me."  In this case, it's more likely the somatic only variant which involves putting thumbs to ears with palms spread and alternately waving them forward and back.

Comment: Yeah... there are *very few* situations where the correct answer for "optimize on keeping myself alive indefinitely" is "alter objectives to now optimize on keeping X alive, even if that means my own destruction".

Comment: Obviously the best way of protecting itself from harm would be produce endless legions of golems, undead, and other mindless servants to purge the multiverse of anything that might potentially harm it in the future.

Comment: @ObliviousSage that's the _Paperclip Guardian_.

Comment: @GcL Death to the Drifters!

Comment: My first thought on Sage's comment was Ultron